# Using Spring, why can H2 transaction rollback work correctly in embedded-database mode, but not in server mode?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, h2, spring-transactions

A simple spring service with method doing insert and throwing Runtime exception after insert.
Runtime exception should cause rollback.

```
@Transactional()
public void insertAndThrowRuntimeEx()  {

    Order order = new Order();

    entityManager.persist(order);

    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected runtime exception");

}
```

Rollback appears correctly only when I configure dataSource with:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" /> <!-- with this configuration there is correct rollback -->
```

But when I use database in standalone mode, there is no rollback, or rollback is not effective:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"    <!-- here inserted record remains in database -->
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" p:url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/databases/test1"
    p:username="sa" p:password="" />
```

**Why can transaction rollback work correctly in H2 embedded-database mode, but not in server mode ?**

ps, 
there is also transaction manager configured

```
    @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager( localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );
    return manager;
}

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**spring debug log says transaction is rolledback:**

now thrownig runtime exception

```
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] - Completing transaction for [com.javatech.training.OrderServiceImpl.insertAndThrowRuntimeEx] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected runtime exception
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected runtime exception
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - <Winning rollback rule is: null>
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 TRACE [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback
2014-07-03 20:02:05,965 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1affcbf9]
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 TRACE [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Clearing transaction synchronization
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2f216eaf] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@3be9bb55] from thread [main]
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@412eb15f] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@24915432] from thread [main]
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1affcbf9] after transaction
2014-07-03 20:02:05,966 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] - Closing JPA EntityManager
CATCH Exception: Unexpected runtime exception
```

**it seems to me, there is sth nok with h2 standalone mode**

Comment: Do you see in logs that a transaction rollback has been initiated?

Comment: Yes, I see spring trace about it, I added it to description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with H2 in standalone mode.
The same code and configuration using mysql works as expected (transactionally, with rollback).

Answer (score 0):

Need transaction manager bean definition for your `dataSource`

For local resource transaction manager;

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

For JTA transaction manager, see more spring doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.0/reference/transaction.html)

Comment: thx for reply, sorry I didn't write earlier, but there is tx manager configured, and it works properly, but only when database is in inmemory mode

Comment: Have you tried with datasource property `defaultAutoCommit` to `false`? Otherwise, you may need to make sure transaction manager config.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with defaultAutoCommit = false, it has no influence. It seems to me, there is sth nok with h2, in logs I see spring transaction rollback, I added full logs to issue description